# Parent script calls child script: how to retain variables set in child script if it exits?

Tags: bash

A parent script calls a child script. The child script sets some variables and exits with an error code. Is it possible for the calling script to retain the variables set in the child script? In this scenario, `child.sh` *cannot* be modified.

I tried combining `source` with `|| true`, but it didn't work.

**parent.sh**

```
source ./child.sh || true

echo "testvar = $testvar"
```

**child.sh**

```
echo "In child script."
testvar="foo"
echo "testvar = $testvar"
exit 1
```

Output:

```
$ ./parent.sh
In child script.
testvar = foo
```

Desired output:

```
$ ./parent.sh
In child script.
testvar = foo
testvar = foo
```

Comment: AFAIK, since `source` executes the script in the current environment, `exit 1` will terminate the current environment. I don't think there is anything you can do about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible. Instead, prevent the script from exiting.

You can generally do this by overriding `exit`:

```
$ cat parent.sh
shopt -s expand_aliases
alias exit=return
source ./child.sh
unalias exit
echo "testvar = $testvar"
```

When executed, the script will be tricked into `return`ing instead:

```
$ bash parent.sh
In child script.
testvar = foo
testvar = foo
```

Answer (score 1):

As Felix noted: `exit 1` will terminate the shell.

But you could activate an `EXIT` [Trap](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_12_02.html):

```bash
#!/bin/bash

function cleanup {
    echo "testvar = ${testvar}"
}

trap cleanup EXIT

source ./child.sh
```

will result in:

```
In child script.
testvar = foo
testvar = foo
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a `return` instead of `exit` in the sourced `child.sh`.

That might be all you need.

```
$: cat parent.sh
echo "in parent, pre child"
source ./child.sh
echo "in parent, post child"
echo "parent: testvar = $testvar"

$: cat child.sh
echo "In child script."
testvar="foo"
echo "child: testvar = $testvar"
return 1
echo never this

$: parent.sh
in parent, pre child
In child script.
child: testvar = foo
in parent, post child
parent: testvar = foo
```